# Most efficient way to access a browser session on a Linux server remotely

Tags: ubuntu, performance, browser, vnc, remote-access

I use a website that allows client side JS scripts to run on a browser session that automate certain actions. I want this script to run 24/7, and thus (by extension) this browser session to be active 24/7, and I don't want to keep my Desktop PC running continuously because of the power consumption. Furthermore, I need to be able to check in on this browser session and the script (preferably from anywhere and without specialized software) to make sure everything's going well.

I already have a decent idea of how to do this: Setup an Ubuntu server with xserver (no desktop), then run a browser and setup noVNC access to it. On my local machine, I can connect to the VNC server through an ordinary client side web browser, then access the website, login and start my script. I can leave the VNC session at any time and the browser session + script will stay alive on the server.

My question is: how can I optimize this? I think there's a lot of unnecessary overhead I can cut out:

- Seems like overkill to run a fully featured browser (eg. Firefox) when I only need to access one website. Is there a very lightweight browser that accesses one page at a time? I do need to interact with the website to do things like adjust the script and 2fa.
- I think VNC is sub optimal because of the performance overhead on the server and the bandwidth required to transmit the whole (virtual) display. Is there a way to just transmit the HTML and browser session instead of the image data of the desktop eg. possibly through a HTML frame element?

I'm working with limited server resources (ec2 T3A Nano - 500 mB RAM, 2 cpu cores), so there's a genuine need for the optimization, but beyond that I think it's a fun problem to solve.

Comment: Did you investigate using web testing tools such as Selenium or Cucumber? That could be a lot simpler.